# Prove $\lambda^2-tr(A)\lambda+\det(A)=0$ is an alternate characteristic equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Prove: The characteristic equation of a $2\times2$ matrix can be expressed as $\lambda^2-tr(A)\lambda+\det(A)=0$.

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ We want to show that the characteristic equation derived from $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ is equivalent to the one shown above. We will define $tr(A)$ and $\det(A)$ for later:

$tr(A)=a+d$

$\det(A)=ad-bc$

So, the characterstic equation is for $A$ is defined as:$$\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{pmatrix}
a-\lambda&b\\
c& d-\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}=0$$ $$(a-\lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc=0$$ $$ad-a\lambda-d\lambda+\lambda^2-bc=0$$

Rearranging and grouping terms: $$\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+(ad-bc)=0$$

Substituting our earlier formulas for $tr(A)$ and $\det(A)$: $$\lambda^2-tr(A)\lambda+\det(A)=0$$

Q.E.D.

Is this proof correct and true in full generality? Is there room to be more formal anywhere? Pointers would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably has a mistake, true form is $\lambda ^2 - \lambda tr(A) + \det (A)$

Comment: It is [true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties) that the first coefficient is always $1$, the second is $(-1)^{n-1}\mathrm{tr}(A)$ and the last is $\det(A)$, but in general the coefficients in between are more complicated, so for $n > 2$ you do not have such a nice description. Your proof looks fine, up to the mistake already mentioned by D F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation comes from the following facts:

1) the trace is a sum of eigenvalues

2) the determinant is the product of eigenvalues

3) Vieta's formulas